# Sendgrid, Heroku Mailer Error Net::SMTPFatalError 553

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, sendgrid

I have my first mailer attempt at hand.  Here is my mailer...

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'http://my-heroku-prename.herokuapp.com'

def welcome_email(current_user)
  @user =  current_user
  @url  = 'http://my-heroku-prename.herokuapp.com/'
  mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
end
end
```

If have this line at the end of my UserController create block

```
   UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
```

I my production.rb looks like this

```
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'my-heroku-prename.heroku.com' }
 ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address    => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port       => 587,
  :user_name  => ENV['my_actually_sendgrid_username'], #should I just put the default here?
  :password   => ENV['my_actually_sendgrid_pw'],
  :domain     => ENV['heroku.com'],
  :authentication => plain
```

There error I get is

```
Net::SMTPFatalError (553 Parse error at ':' of ('<http://me-heroku-prename.herokuapp.com>', [':', '//my-heroku-prename', '.', 'herokuapp', '.', 'com'])
```

I've searched this 553 parse error but couldn't find anything... Is this just a synxtax thing?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `default from:` should be an email address rather than a URL. This specifies the address that will appear as the from in emails sent.

You can modify the from on a per message basis by putting it in your Mailer's methods.